# Grouping data of multiple rows into groups according to an id in codeigniter

Tags: rest, codeigniter

I have a table like this in database

```
  +---+-------------+--------------+
  |id | service_name| doc_id |org_id|  
  +---+-------------+--------------+
  | 1 | new service | 12     | 119  |
  |   |             |        |      |
  | 2 | new service | 24     | 119  |
  |   |             |        |      |
  | 3 | old service | 13     | 118  |
  |   |             |        |      |
  | 4 | old service | 14     | 118  |
  |   |             |        |      |
  | 5 | new service | 20     | 119  |
  +---+-------------+--------------+
```

I want to group all the doc_id's according to service_name column

I have tried using

IN my controller

```
 $where_person['org_id'] = $this->post('org_id');  
 $result_insert = $this->$model_name->fetch_doctor_services($where_person);
```

In my Model

```
   function fetch_doctor_services($where){
    $this->db->select('service_name,doc_id')->from('services');

    $this->db->group_by('service_name');
    $this->db->where($where);

    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

But it does not output data as i desire, by grouping by service_name and all the doc_id's according to that service_name.
where am i going wrong here?
 Currently my output is like this.

```
       { "data":
          [ { "service_name": "new service", "doc_id": "12" }, 
            { 
            "service_name": "old service", "doc_id": "13" } 
                  ] 
                }
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: { "data":
 [ 
 { "service_name": "new service", 
 "doc_id" : "12", 
  "doc_id": "24",
  "doc_id : "20"
  }, 
 {"service_name": "old service", 
 "doc_id": "13",
  "doc_id" : "14"
  } 
 ] 
}

Comment: is this kind of output possible? I doubt it but I kind of need it.

Comment: This is not a Valid JSON

Comment: what i mean to get is two objects within an array and in that two objects i need all the doc_id's related to that service name

Comment: or maybe some other way but i need to group the these doc_id's according to the service name.

Comment: Added an Answer. This should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP_CONCAT`. See below code on how to use it

```
    $this->db->select('service_name, GROUP_CONCAT( doc_id) ')->from('services');
    $this->db->group_by('service_name');
    $this->db->where($where);
    return $this->db->get()->result();
```

Comment: I also need to make a join using these doc_id as a foreign key from my services table to the person table such that first_name of the concat doc_id's are fetched under the service name.